# My Table is Moving When I Fullscreen. Anyone Know Why?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know why my project is like this when small tabed, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc1OH.png)

But when full screened like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CFuS.png)

My grid has the css of:

.table{

position: absolute;

margin-top: 37em;

margin-left: -42em;

min-width: 1015px;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style will depend on how it was created in your workflow, but you can try this class

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
 table: {
   minWidth: 650,
 },
});
```

or

```
.table {
  min-width: 650px !important;
}
```

But this limitation on the size of the table may be related to the element or container that is related to the table.

You also do not need to declare the table's position since it is inherent to your parent and is not placing it in a specific place.

Could you show us how you are applying these classes in your code. You only showed us a small piece of code and did not present the application for that class.

You can also see class applications and table usage on the Material-UI page

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: You can see example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wpzrl?file=/demo.js:446-515

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to publish with your question the code where it is generating this situation, just seeing images is difficult to understand your problem

Comment: this is not an answer it is a comment

Answer (score 0):

change your css like

```
.table{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 37em;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```